# Progress dialog not appearing in database operation inside AsynTask

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I'm inserting some data in my app's local database inside AysncTask, but when executing the class the progress dialog is not showing on the screen while i can see the running log. I see many related answer but the issue is not resolved. I read the .get() method blocks the ui but I'm already not using this method. I don't why it is not showing on the screen

calling async class from main Activity

```
 AsyncGetDataFromServer task = new AsyncGetDataFromServer(this);
 task.execute();
```

code of AsyncTask class

```
public class AsyncGetDataFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

ProgressDialog pd;
Context cxt;
DatabaseHandler dbHelper;
private static ArrayList<DataModel> categoryArrayList;

public AsyncGetDataFromServer(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    cxt= context;
    pd = new ProgressDialog(cxt);
    pd.setTitle("Please wait");
    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(cxt);
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
{
    try {
        Log.d("do in background","true");

                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getVideoEntity().size(); i++) {
                    //inserting in categories
                    VideoEntity videoEntity;
                    videoEntity = response.body().getVideoEntity().get(i);
                    dbHelper.insertChannels(videoEntity);
                }        
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("exception error", e.getMessage());
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Log.d("on pre execute","true");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Log.d("on post execute","true");
    pd.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: Put all code wrote in constructor to onPreExecuate method and chk and remove that constructor

Comment: I test it already but did not work.

Comment: With above code and try this new AsyncGetDataFromServer().execute();

Comment: @Sumant It flashed in the beginning and disappeared.

Comment: G8.. Just chk how many time your loop got executed? if you want for more time, for time being just add timer to chk, progress dialog is displayed for few seconds

Answer (score 0):

pass Activity instead of context to the constructor.For example-

```
    AsyncGetDataFromServer task = new AsyncGetDataFromServer(MyActivity.this);
 task.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the method `onProgressUpdate` and use the method `publishProgress` :

see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Show dialog in onPreExecute() method & dismiss in onPostExecute() method:

```
private class AsyncGetDataFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
  private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourClass.this);

  protected void onPreExecute() {
     this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
     this.dialog.show();
  }

  protected void doInBackground(final Void unused) {
     //don't interact with the ui!
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean result) {
     if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
        this.dialog.dismiss();
     }
  }
}
```